# In android, How to call a get api method inside firebase onMessageReceived when the app is closed

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, push-notification, android-push-notification

How to call a get api method inside firebase onMessageReceived when the app is closed or how to start a foreground service when we receive push notification (the app is closed, even the app is not in background)